# i noticed these odd lines in my /var/log/kern.log file, what are they?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, logs

I am running Ubuntu 19.04, after installing virtualbox and rebooting, i noticed these non-descriptive lines in the /var/log/kern.log

```
Sep 30 16:36:34 a kernel: [  236.760271] test1
Sep 30 16:36:34 a kernel: [  236.760273] test2
Sep 30 16:41:07 a kernel: [  509.036723] test1
Sep 30 16:41:07 a kernel: [  509.036726] test2
Sep 30 16:41:25 a kernel: [  527.214838] test1
Sep 30 16:41:25 a kernel: [  527.214840] test2
```

What could they be?

Output of

```
sudo grep -wri kern /etc/*syslog*

/etc/rsyslog.d/20-ufw.conf:# normally containing kern.* messages (eg, /var/log/kern.log)
/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf:kern.*                           -/var/log/kern.log
```

Thanks

Comment: `grep -wri kern /etc/*syslog*` please. I'm expecting just one line; if there are more it's a sign of a possible problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>This has been taken from https://wiki.chotaire.net/vbox-test-warning-messages. Kudos to them. If it helps you, please consider visiting them and letting them know it was helpful.</sub>

---

The source code for Virtual Box 6.0.6 shows kernel print statements that have been accidentally left in the production release. If you're using `rsyslog` you can filter them out by adding two lines to `/etc/rsyslog.conf` - or create your own `/etc/rsyslog.d/vbox.conf` for easier administration (remember to comment there what you've done):

```
:msg, contains, "test1" stop
:msg, contains, "test2" stop
```

This has been fixed by Oracle and was released in VirtualBox Version 6.0.8.